# Region monitoring beacon regions in background not working

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

I have a problem with region monitoring while the app is in background.
Region enters and exits get called if the app is in foreground, but doesn't while in the background (sometimes they fire but very rarely).

How does beacon region monitoring work for iOS 8.1.1 ? Should region enters/exit fire instantly when in Beacon proximity while in background ?

What should I do to make sure it works ?

Do `Background Modes` : `Location Updates` or `Uses Bluetooth LE accessories` have to be on for background beacon monitoring to work ? GeoFencing worked for me without having these on.

What I've already done:

- set these for every region:

  `beaconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
  beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
  beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;`
- Made sure that everything in settings is in order (app refresh etc.)

EDIT:

I've created a new project and it still doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {



_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 25;
_locationManager.delegate = self;
[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLBeaconRegion* reg =[self prepareBeacon:@"here i put my UUID" :446 :2196];
[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:reg];
[_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:reg];

return YES;
}

-(CLBeaconRegion*)prepareBeacon:(NSString*)uuid :(int)maj :(int)min
{

NSString* identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d,%d", uuid, maj, min];

CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuid] major:maj  minor:min identifier:identifier];

beaconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

return beaconRegion;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state           forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{

}
```

some additional info:

- Except creating a fresh iOS8 project and adding code I've added `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to *.plist file.
- I put breakpoints in `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion`. It works in foreground, doesn't work while in background (iPhone in home screen or locked)
- Testing on 4S, iOS 8.1.1

Comment: No need to set Background Modes for iBeacons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: background region monitoring is a mystery to us users. Sometimes it fires up in a second, sometimes it takes longer. It depends on a lot of factors but my main problem was that I was using iPhone 4s.

Maybe this will help anyone without losing so much time: **4s sucks at background beacons scanning**

source: tested on two 4S phones with latest iOS and iPhone 6. iPhone6 gets beacon notifications in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you have called the method under CCLocationManager

```
- (void) requestAlwaysAuthorization
```

This allows your app to be updated about changes in the foreground and background compared to the line below that only allows your app to be notified while in the foreground:

```
- (void) requestWhenInUseAuthorization
```

Once the user responds to the request the following method will be called with the updated authorization status:

```
- (void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager*) manager
didChangeAuthorizationStatus: (CLAuthorizationStatus) status
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager

Comment: That's what I'm using. I also have that value needed for always auth. in *.plist

Comment: The worst thing is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I've tested on two iPhone 4S.

Comment: Strange.  Let me think of another reason why that would be caused.

Comment: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html

what about this. Is this still up to date ? Could region updates really take up to 15 minutes in background ?

Also, I've updated my post with code example.